# Why is the wireframe showing in rendered view?

Tags: shaders

[image]
Does anyone know why I can see a triangulated wireframe with this shader setup? Glossy, Glass, and Translucent shader mixed with any emissive shader produces the undesired effect. Object is a plane. I've tried remaking the shader from scratch. I've applied the shader to a new object. I've tried it in 3.4 and 3.5. The effect is the same.

Thanks in advance for any help! <3

Comment: Hello could you please share an object with the same material? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: And now, of course, it doesn't do it when I open a new project and paste the objects/materials into it. I did this yesterday and it was doing the same thing. Maybe that was when I was still using 3.4? Idk, Either way, that's for getting me to do it again because that seems to be an acceptable solution (even though I'm still curious why it's rendering differently in another file).